# How to use rest params with already defined params, eslint prefer-rest-params

Tags: typescript, arguments, eslint

I am currently logging out the arguments of a function with console.log(arguments), but eslint is telling me not to `Use the rest parameters instead of 'arguments'  prefer-rest-params'`

In the docs, I can see how to use rest params if in the functions arguments if the parameters include `...args`, but i can't see how to have the names and types of the params defined and then use rest params.

Here's my method (in a class with a logger):

```
doStuff(
        firstName: string,
        lastName: string,
        files: File[]
    ) {
        this.logger.log(`Print args: ${arguments}`);
}
```

If I try with rest params, like this...
`` this.logger.log(`Print args: ${...args}`); `` I get the error `Cannot find name 'args'` but i don't want to remove the names and types of the parameters in order to log them. I guess I could just write each param out, but there must be a way to do it like with 'arguments'.

What am I missing? (I know this doesn't really make much difference to my code, since I don't want to use any array methods on the arguments, but would like to know what the right way to do this would be.)
Thanks!

Comment: It's a linter, if you don't like what it's enforcing, you don't have to use that rule. The rule says you should not use `arguments` but you want to use arguments. You can ignore a rule for one line, but if you think there's value in the rule, just use the parameter names, it does not seem like a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose one way would be rest params and destructuring them?

```
doStuff(...args: [firstName: string, lastName: string, files: File[]]) {
    const [firstName, lastName, files] = args;
    
    // Shouldn't this be log(`Print args: `, ...args), too?
    this.logger.log(`Print args: ${args}`);
}
```

You could leave out the names in the named tuple, but then intellisense/suggestions in the editor would result in unhelpful names like `args_0`.

Comment: Don't make your code so hard to read just to satisfy a lint requirement